# JavaFX how to make circle act like ball ,"I need to make the circle jump vertically"

Tags: javafx

this code for circle its dosen't work(jump) ?? any suggestion

```
//1- move the circle  up  with position variable" 100"
// 2-return the circle  Down  with position variable " 100" 

scene.setOnKeyReleased(e ->{    //event handler for space 
    switch (e.getCode()) {
        case SPACE:
            circle.setTranslateY(circle.getCenterY()+ position);
            break;

    }
});

scene.setOnKeyPressed(e ->{

    System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + e.getCode());
        try{
            switch (e.getCode()) 

                case SPACE:
                    circle.setTranslateY(circle.getCenterY()- position);
                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't do your work, since this requires a lot of reading, but this subject may be interesting also for other people, so here you go:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static double SCENE_WIDTH = 800;
    public static double SCENE_HEIGHT = 600;

    public static int SPRITE_COUNT = 20;

    public static Point2D FORCE_WIND = new Point2D(0, 0);
    public static Point2D FORCE_GRAVITY = new Point2D(0, 3);

    public static double SPRITE_ACCELERATION_SCALE = 0.5;
    public static double SPRITE_MAX_SPEED = 4;



    public static Random random = new Random();

    Pane playfield;

    List<Sprite> allSprites = new ArrayList<>();

    AnimationTimer gameLoop;

    Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create containers
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        // entire game as layers
        StackPane layerPane = new StackPane();

        // playfield for our Sprites
        playfield = new Pane();
        playfield.setPrefSize(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);

        layerPane.getChildren().addAll(playfield);

        root.setCenter(layerPane);

        scene = new Scene(root, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // add content
        prepareGame();

        // run animation loop
        startGame();

    }

    private void prepareGame() {

        // add sprites
        for (int i = 0; i < SPRITE_COUNT; i++) {
            addSprite();
        }

    }

    private void startGame() {

        // start game
        gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // physics: apply forces
                allSprites.forEach(s -> s.applyForce(FORCE_GRAVITY));
                allSprites.forEach(s -> s.applyForce(FORCE_WIND));

                // move
                allSprites.forEach(Sprite::move);

                // check boundaries
                allSprites.forEach(Sprite::checkBounds);

                // update in fx scene
                allSprites.forEach(Sprite::display);

            }
        };

        gameLoop.start();

    }

    private void addSprite() {

        // random location
        double x = random.nextDouble() * playfield.getWidth();
        double y = random.nextDouble() * playfield.getHeight();

        // create sprite data
        Point2D location = new Point2D(x, y);
        Point2D velocity = new Point2D(0, 0);
        Point2D acceleration = new Point2D(0, 0);
        double mass = random.nextDouble() * 50 + 20; // at least 20 pixels, max 50 pixels

        // create sprite and add to layer
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(playfield, location, velocity, acceleration, mass);

        // register sprite
        allSprites.add(sprite);

    }

    public static class Sprite extends Region {

        Point2D location;
        Point2D velocity;
        Point2D acceleration;

        double mass;
        double maxSpeed = SPRITE_MAX_SPEED;

        Node view;

        // view dimensions
        double width = 30;
        double height = width;
        double centerX = width / 2.0;
        double centerY = height / 2.0;
        double radius = width / 2.0;

        Pane layer;

        public Sprite( Pane layer, Point2D location, Point2D velocity, Point2D acceleration, double mass) {

            this.layer = layer;

            this.location = location;
            this.velocity = velocity;
            this.acceleration = acceleration;
            this.mass = mass;

            // initialize view depending on mass
            width = mass;
            height = width;
            centerX = width / 2.0;
            centerY = height / 2.0;
            radius = width / 2.0;

            // create view
            Circle circle = new Circle( radius);
            circle.setCenterX(radius);
            circle.setCenterY(radius);

            circle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            circle.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3));

            this.view = circle;

            // add view to this node
            getChildren().add( view);

            layer.getChildren().add( this);
        }

        public void applyForce(Point2D force) {

            Point2D f = force.multiply( 1.0 / mass);

            acceleration = acceleration.add(f);

        }

        /**
         * Move sprite
         */
        public void move() {

            // set velocity depending on acceleration
            velocity = velocity.add(acceleration);

            // limit velocity to max speed
            if( velocity.magnitude() > maxSpeed) {
                velocity = velocity.normalize().multiply(maxSpeed);
            }

            // change location depending on velocity
            location = location.add(velocity);

            // clear acceleration
            acceleration = new Point2D( 0, 0);
        }

        /**
         * Ensure sprite can't go outside bounds
         */
        public void checkBounds() {

            double locationX = location.getX();
            double locationY = location.getY();
            double velocityX = velocity.getX();
            double velocityY = velocity.getY();

            if (location.getX() > layer.getWidth() - radius) {
                locationX = layer.getWidth() - radius;
                velocityX *= -1;
            } else if (location.getX() < 0 + radius) {
                velocityX *= -1;
                locationX = 0 + radius;
            }

            // reverse direction to bounce off floor
            if (locationY > layer.getHeight() - radius) {
                velocityY *= -1;
                locationY = layer.getHeight() - radius;
            }

            location = new Point2D( locationX, locationY);
            velocity = new Point2D( velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        /**
         * Update node position
         */
        public void display() {
            relocate(location.getX() - centerX, location.getY() - centerY);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

About the physics you should read [The Nature of Code, Chapter 2, Forces](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-2-forces/).

Regarding the vectors: I used the JavaFX Point2D mechanism with which you always have to create new objects. However, in the end you should use your own Vector2D classes in which you don't have to do that and instead just manipulate the attributes.